# Add a meta_key when creating a new product

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, post, woocommerce

I created this function to generate a new position in the database with metakey: “_price” because when I create a new product from frontend this is empty. The code works only when I update the post, not when I create it for the first time the product.
Can you help me? Thank you !!

```
function wpufe_update_post_price( $post_id ) {
if ( 'product' != $_POST['post_type'] )
return;

$regular_price = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', true );
$sale_price = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', true );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $regular_price );

if ( !empty( $sale_price ) ) {

    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_price', $sale_price );

}

}
add_action('save_post_product', 'wpufe_update_post_price', 10, 1);
 add_action('wp_insert_post', 'wpufe_update_post_price', 10, 1);
```